# error: "net.core.wmem_default" is an unknown key on Juju local provider

Tags: juju

I create and deploy HPCC charm on local provider. For single node It run OK. For multiple nodes after configure the cluster one of the component fails to start with error:

```
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max value 0 is less than 131071
EXCEPTION: (1455): System socket max read buffer is less than 131071
```

I try to set `net.core.rmem_max` with sysctl but got error "net.core.rmem_max" is an unknown key

I notice there is no rmem_max under /proc/sys/net/core/ for local provider.

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since the local provider runs on your machine, changing the `sysctl` settings on it will affect all instances the local provider sees. I'm not quite sure what do you mean you can't find `/proc/sys/net/core/net.core.rmem_max` for the local provider.

You can run the following to change `net.core.rmem_max` setting immediately:

`sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=131071` (or a higher value, if necessary)

If you want to persist the set value after a reboot, add the following line at the end of `/etc/sysctl.conf` instead:

`net.core.rmem_max = 131071`

Then, to apply the change immediately run:

`sudo sysctl -p`

You might need to modify other similar settings, if you're still getting errors. I found [this interesting article](http://www.santa-li.com/linuxonbb.html), explaining the location of all these settings and their meaning. You might find it useful, although it's unrelated to your exact issue.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply. My host Linux systems (Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10) are fine with the net.core.rmem_max resources. My application run OK also. The problem is juju lxc local instance. It doesn't have this key and other networks keys. I can't add them in the instance with sysclt. It seems a bug with juju local provider or some conflict configuration on my systems.

Comment: On the instance, I briefly cheched /var/log/dmesg, syslog but don't see related errors. But on /var/log/upstart there are errors from acpid, apport, moudles-init-tools, procps-xxx etc log. On the host system, lxc.log is clean

Comment: files under /proc/sys/net/core/      <br/>  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 24 17:58 somaxconn
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 24 18:07 xfrm_acq_expires
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 24 18:07 xfrm_aevent_etime
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 24 18:07 xfrm_aevent_rseqth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 24 18:07 xfrm_larval_drop <br/>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13237/discussion-between-dimitern-and-user235342)

Comment: Even login as root I got the same results